# Decomposition field of the polynomial $t^3-3$

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory

The problem is to find the degree of the decomposition field of $t^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I have already proven that this field is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$ where $\alpha =\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. However now I need to find the degree of the extension. I apply transitivity and I know that the grade is a multiple of $3$. I also have a theorem that says it is less than $3!=6$ because that is the degree of the polynomial. Now I need to decide if it is $3$ or $6$. I am pretty sure it is $6$ and all I have to do is show that $\omega$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ but this is proving very hard. I attempt to write it in the basis $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ but that yields a very complicated set of equations and I struggle to reach a contradiction. Is there an easy way to show that $\omega$ cannot be in this set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\alpha$ is real, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset\mathbb{R}$, but $\omega\not\in\mathbb{R}$, hence $\omega\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Here's another way . . .

The minimal polynomial for $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^2+x+1$, hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

But $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=3$, hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega):\mathbb{Q}]$ must be a multiple of both $2$ and $3$.